# Last() function in SSRS. How do I define a group?

Tags: sql, function, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

My end goal is only showing a field if the row is the last of a GROUP.

I think that I can accomplish this by saying if the row number is the last of the group, show the row.  How do I specify that in the visibility expression?

Currently I am trying this:

```
=IIF((RowNumber("LINE_No") = Count("LINE_NO)), True, False)
```

I know I'm off.  What I have is 3 LINE_NOs corresponding to different groups.  So I want the field to show at the last line of each group, I just can't distinguish it.  Let me know if you need more pictures or context.

Really, I just don't know how to define that group, as opposed to the entire data set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are stuck with this requeriment, seeing this and another related questions you posted this is what a I get you need.

I've recreated your scenario using this dataset:

[image]

I've added a tablix with these data arrangement.

[image]

It will produce the note at the very end of every `Line` group.

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the tablix stuff.  How is your solution working? I added an incrementing row count and just made an if clause and have it working now, but yours looks possibly more efficient.

Comment: Just right click `Data` cell and add row add a row outside the `details2` group but inside the `Line` group as seen in the second screenshot. Set the expression in the added cell below `Data`.